# (admin.E030) The value of 'prepopulated_fields["slug"][0]' refers to 'name', which is not a field of 'store.Category'

Tags: python, django

I'm making an ecommerce app with Django. The command terminal keeps popping the above error whenever I try to run a command with it.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 150, db_index = True),
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 150, unique = True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name = 'product', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name= 'product_creator')
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 150, default = 'admin')
    description = models.TextField(blank = True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 150)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 4, decimal_places = 2)
    in_stock = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Products'
        ordering = ('-created',)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, Product

@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'slug']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug' : ('name',)}

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'author', 'slug', 'price', 'in_stock', 'created', 'updated']
    list_filter = ['in_stock', 'is_active']
    list_editable = ['price', 'in_stock']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug' : ('title',)}
```

It's also worth noting that for whatever reason, the database created by Django when I created the original migrations didn't include the name field in Category, and I had to fight Django to force it to add it, but it still doesn't see it for some reason?

Comment: remove the trailing comma from `name = ...,`.

Comment: Oh my god that's embarrassing. I'm still not fully used to python's syntax, having initially come from C/C++. I fixed that and it works fine now ty